# ssrs skipping date parameter for an expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report in ssrs which calculates and compares different values for each customer. I have set two date parameters using `memrepay.pday`, FROM and TO.

e.g. we want all purchases `(=SUM(Field!memrepay.mprinc.Value)` by "Customer-1" FROM: 5/1/2015 TO: 5/31/2015 (easy enough). But also, all the purchases done from the beginning of his membership up TO:5/31/2015 in another cell, which is the same `(=SUM(Field!memrepay.mprinc.Value)`.

Is it possible to skip the selected "FROM" date for this expression and allow the expression to sum all paid amounts, from beginning, up to selected "TO" parameter?

```
`SELECT
  memrepay.lnr
  ,memrepay.pday
  ,memrepay.tcode
  ,memdues.dday
  ,memrepay.mprinc AS [memrepay mprinc]
  ,memrepay.mint AS [memrepay mint]
  ,memdues.mprinc AS [memdues mprinc]
  ,memdues.mint AS [memdues mint]

FROM
  memdues
  INNER JOIN memrepay
    ON memdues.lnr = memrepay.lnr AND memdues.memid = memrepay.memid
  INNER JOIN loan
    ON loan.lnr = memrepay.lnr AND loan.memid = memrepay.memid
WHERE
  memdues.dday >= @dday
  AND memdues.dday <= @dday2
  AND memrepay.pday >= @pday
  AND memrepay.pday <= @pday2`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the data back in your query and then filter using your **To Date** parameter like:

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!YourDateField.VALUE <= Parameters!ToDate.Value  ,Field!paidamount.Value, 0))
```

Or between both dates:

```
=SUM(IIF(FIELDS!YourDateField.VALUE <= Parameters!ToDate.Value AND FIELDS!YourDateField.VALUE >= Parameters!FromDate.Value,Field!paidamount.Value, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this one didn't work. To be sure that I have set the right expression, can you tell me what field you exactly mean by "FIELDS!YourDateField.VALUE", payment date?

Comment: The YourDateField would be the date field that you have in your data to filter it - **"by "Customer-1" FROM: 5/1/2015 TO: 5/31/2015 (easy enough). "**

Comment: Ok, in my case it is "Fields!pday.Value". I tried it, but it is still not giving the total from beginning: =SUM(IIF(Fields!pday.Value <= Parameters!pday2.Value ,Fields!payment.Value, 0)).                                                                                                                          Is it possible to set the calculation date range for this expression next to SUM. e.g. From: 1/1/2000 To: (Selected To date)?

Comment: Yes - you can add a FROM part to the date expression.

**=SUM(IIF(Fields!pday.Value <= Parameters!pday2.Value AND Fields!pday.Value>= "1/1/2000" ,Fields!payment.Value, 0))**

Comment: Thanks, but this one didn't work either. I need to come up with an expression to SUM payment value FROM "1/1/2000" to selected TO date parameter. I appreciate if you mention possible expression(s).

Comment: Are you getting an **error** or a wrong answer? Details of an error should be in the **Error List** window. Is your field **text** or a **date** type? Is your field **payment** or **paidamount**?

Comment: Actual field name is longer, I just used friendly name here and second time i changed it - forgetting what i mentioned earlier. lets call this field "payment". Yes, I get the #Error, but I am using Report builder and can't find Error List window. I used the date in expression without quotes as using quotes will not show the total either. Payment field type in database is numeric(14, 2), and in report I have also used Number.

Comment: Damn - I forgot about mixed data types.Try using **CDEC(0)** to see if the issue is that it can't add two data types.  **=SUM(IIF(Fields!pday.Value <= Parameters!pday2.Value AND Fields!pday.Value>= "1/1/2000", Fields!payment.Value, CDEC(0) ))**

Comment: Thanks, sorry but this one didn't work too. I have edited the main post and added the query to it. if that helps.

Comment: Hmm - I can't think of anything else that could be causing the issue right now other than bad data or your field names ([memrepay mprinc] = memrepay.mprinc?). To troubleshoot, I would start with summing just the field. It that works without an error, add the first part of the IIF (=SUM(**IIF(Fields!pday.Value <= Parameters!pday2.Value, Fields!payment.Value, CDEC(0) ))** )and test etc until you get the error.

Comment: Good news, it eventually worked. But I had to make many other changes in report as well. First, I removed "pday" filters, then I applied your expression to all other fields too, and also changed grouping by pday instead of customer's name. So now, most importantly the numbers are correct, however, the presentation is not exactly as I wanted. Thanks, you've been great help. I don't think we can mark a comment as answer, but if you post it as answer, I will. Thanks again!